# Cast json object dynamically to a specific C# class object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, dynamic

I am receiving an object and, according to a parameter, I need to cast it into a specific C# object.

Can I replace the following functionality?

```
object objectTobeParsed;
switch (formId)
{
     case 1: var myObject = objectTobeParsed as MyClass;
     /* other cases here */

     /* other cases here */

     /* other cases here */

}
```

As you can see, there are a lot of switch cases.

Thanks,
Anish.

Comment: I just wnat to avoid the lengthy switch with elegent c# code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have so many alternatives to a switch/case statement.

In your case, the statement to execute for each case is specific, because you have to cast to a precise class. In my opinion, there isn't much more to do, except if the classes you have to cast to your object are linked to a common interface and maybe you can use polymorphism.

The problem, as pointed out in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187010) isn't the length of the switch/case but the number of times you have the switch. If the statement is repeated so many times, maybe you have to review the design of your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the type of code that OOP is trying to prevent.

What is currently preventing you from just passing in a base class/interface, and using it further, without a cast to a more specific class?

A workaround would be to use [T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx) and generate the switch code from a Dictionary of int and Type.